How can I integrate java splash screen into flutter application?
I want to use the java splash screen in my flutter application. All the permissions required by the app are requested on the java splash screen and then a foreground intent is started in a new thread on the splash screen.
I have tried to create the communication channel for this but i don't know how to do it just for the splash screen that is asking for permissions and starting a foreground intent

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
